# Python timer not waiting as expected

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

So, I have this code:

```
t = threading.Timer(570.0, reddit_post(newmsg))
t.start()
```

To start a quick Reddit post. Sadly, instead of waiting 570 seconds, it automatically executes reddit_post without actually waiting.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain in more detail:

When you call the Timer constructor, you should give it three arguments. The first argument should be how long you want the timer to wait. The second argument should be a callable (for example a function). The third argument should be a list of arguments with which to call the function.

An example.

```
# First we define a function to call.
def say_hello(name):
    print('hello ' + name)

# Now we can call this function.
say_hello('john')

# But when we make a timer to call it later, we do not call the function.
timer = threading.Timer(10, say_hello, ['john'])
timer.start()
```

Answer (score 5):

That is because you are actually calling the function instead of passing the arguments to the `Timer` class when you say `t = threading.Timer(570.0, reddit_post(newmsg))`

What you need to do is this:

```
threading.Timer(570.0, reddit_post, [newmsg]).start()
```

Refer to the [documentation of the Timer class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects)

Comment: So what can I do to not call the function?

Comment: Can't you use sleep to stall?

Comment: @abhiii5459 sleep will put the current thread to sleep and not the thread you want to defer. That's not what the OP wants.